# Anti-symmetric energy-momentum tensor Maxwell theory

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given the Lagrangian for Maxwell field:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
I'm using the 'almost minus' metric signiture $(+---)$. Upon an infinitesimal Poincare transformation, we find the energy-momentum tensor. Here it is:
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=-F^{\rho\mu}\partial^{\nu}A_{\rho}-\mathcal{L}g^{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}

> How to show that this tensor is anti-symmetric?

My attempt: Act on two basis vectors (partial derivatives) but I got stuck. Is there an easier way to see wether a given two rank tensor is symmetric/anti-symmetric?

Comment: but it's symmetric isn't it?

Comment: At first, I thought the same. but it's an exam question, so I doubt my instructor made a mistake.

Comment: I am relatively confident that your instructor made a mistake.

Comment: Could be the case. However, check this link: http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~shapiro/613/615lects/maxwTmunu_2.pdf .

Comment: The metric tensor is always symmetric.

Comment: the metric is always symmetric, indeed. an antisymmetric object can be written as a sum of (symmetric +arbitrary). for example: $\sin(x)= [\cos(x)+\sin(x)] -\cos(x)$

Answer (score 2):

The equations you wrote down are equations between *components* of the tensor. These components are already the result of acting with the tensors on the basis vectors.

You just need to prove that $T^{\mu\nu} = - T^{\nu\mu}$. To do so, expand everything in terms of the derivatives of the vector potential and do some index shuffling.